# Can I detect Amazon tablet and others?

Tags: android, device

I have been using Google service in my project, but Amazon tablets don't support Google service so that if I want to publish app to Amazon Store, I need to remove Google service. 
I don't want to divide project to "For Google Play" and "For Amazon Store".
I get device name using `android.os.Build.MODEL` but I'm not sure it's safe?
Can I detect Amazon tablets in project?

```
if(is Amazon) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use Build.MODEL and Build.MANUFACTURER.

As per [Amazon documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html), Build.MANUFACTURER always returns "Amazon", and Build.MODEL returns different strings, depending on the model.

If you don't need to distinguish between each Amazon tablet, you can just use:

```
if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Amazon")) {
    //we have an Amazon tablet
}
else {
    //some other device
}
```

If you need to know exactly which device it is, you can use Build.MODEL, for example:

- Kindle Fire HDX 8.9 (3rd Gen)

  ```
  if (Build.MODEL.equals("KFAPWI")) {
      //WiFi version
  }
  else if (Build.MODEL.equals("KFAPWA")) {
      //WAN version
  }
  ```

  etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ..

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

For more details please visit [**android.os.Build**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to detect wether google Play is installed. Because a few Custom Roms do not have intsalled Google Play either. So try it with this lines of code:

```
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameOld = "com.google.market";
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameNew = "com.google.vending";

public boolean serviceAvailable(Context ctx) {
    boolean googlePlayStoreInstalled= false;
    packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
    for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if (packageInfo.packageName.equals(GooglePlayStorePackageNameOld) ||
            packageInfo.packageName.equals(GooglePlayStorePackageNameNew)) {
            googlePlayStoreInstalled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return googlePlayStoreInstalled;
}
```